# SoftLayer_User_Customer::GetObject softlayer failed with Exception

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I called service.GetObject() method it will return Softlayer 
  exception.
  Can anyone help me out what I have done wrong.

```
sess := session.New(s.UserName, s.Apikey)

service := services.GetUserCustomerService(sess)
user, err := service.GetObject()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error that you got is because you need to use a user ID identifier.

Add this userId to you go code, like this example:

```
   userId := 11111

   // Create a session
   sess := session.New(username, apikey)

   // Get SoftLayer_User_Customer service
   service := services.GetUserCustomerService(sess)

   result, err := service.Id(userId).GetObject()
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getObject/

If you want to get a specific userId of your account, use this go code example:
You have to put your username in the object filter  ¨ Eq("set me")¨ to get the specific userId .

```
package main

/*
GetUsers

Retrieve an account’s portal users.

Important manual pages:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers/

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/

import (
       "fmt"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
       "encoding/json"
       "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/filter"
)

func main() {
       // SoftLayer API username and key
       username := "set me"
       apikey   := "set me"

       filter := filter.Build(
                     filter.Path("users.username").Eq("set me"),
              )
       mask := "id"

       // Create a session
       sess := session.New(username, apikey)

       // Get SoftLayer_Account service
       service := services.GetAccountService(sess)

       result, err := service.Mask(mask).Filter(filter).GetUsers()

       if err != nil {
              fmt.Printf("\n Unable to retrieve User:\n - %s\n", err)
              return
       }
       // Following helps to print the result in json format.
       jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(result,"","     ")
       if jsonErr != nil {
              fmt.Println(jsonErr)
              return
       }
       fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

Comment: Thanks such for great help.. small question I have how did you find in filter I have use "users.username"  and if multiple condition how would I use?

Comment: For me help me for below code sample                                             
 mask := "mask[podName,account[id],datacenter[name]]"
 filter := filter.Build(
  filter.Path("subnet.podName").Eq(s.PodName),
 )    It is not working

Comment: To start with the filters you have to see first at the method you are using in this case we are using the method "getUsers" that is why the filter should start with "users" it is done by removing the value "get", then will be added the attributes from which you want to obtain your information like this “users.username”. It is the same for multiples conditions. See the following documentation: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/blob/master/examples/filters.go

Comment: So how to filter relational data. I have already did the masking ..like mask := "mask[podName,account[id],datacenter[name]]"...but still i am not able to filter the data

Comment: I investigated more about this, your filter should work because the attribute podName is in the database, trying with your filter I got error as well, so this is an issue, You can report this issue on this page: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/issues/. Local and Relational data works for filters, see this documentation: https://softlayer.github.io/article/object-filters/. I tried you object mask and it works in my example code.

Comment: Did you add the Mask data to your go code? like this : user, err := service.Mask(mask).GetSubnets()

Comment: Try adding the rest endpoint to your code, like this: endpoint := "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3"

// Create a session
sess := session.New(username, apikey, endpoint)

Comment: The Rest endpoint that I sent you was to try the object Mask to run without the object Filter because the attribute that you want to get the information “podName” is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use the primaryRouter.hostname instead of podName, the filter is something like below:

```
package main

/*
GetPrivateSubnets

Retrieve all private subnets associated with an account.

Important manual pages:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateSubnets/

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/filter"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"

    mask := "mask[podName,datacenter[name],networkVlan]"

    filter := filter.Build( filter.Path("privateSubnets.datacenter.name").Eq("dal09"),
        filter.Path("privateSubnets.networkVlan.primaryRouter.hostname").Contains("bcr06"),
        )


    // Create a session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Get SoftLayer_Account service
    service := services.GetAccountService(sess)

    result, err := service.Mask(mask).Filter(filter).GetPrivateSubnets()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to retrieve the private subnets:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(result,"","     ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

bcr06 means that the subnet has conection through the backend network (private) of pod06.

The response is something like below:

```
"datacenter": {
            "name": "dal09"
        },
        "networkVlan": {
            "id": 111333322,
            "modifyDate": "2016-09-14T13:24:10-04:00",
            "primarySubnetId": 1225544,
            "vlanNumber": 111,
            "primaryRouter": {
                "domain": "softlayer.com",
                "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "bcr06a.dal09.softlayer.com",
                                "hostname": "bcr06a.dal09",
            }
        },
        "podName": "dal09.pod06"
```

Comment: What is "bcr06" how to get the value if I know only podname and datacenter name

Comment: ¨podName¨ = dal09.pod06 = Dallas 9, Pod 6 (ie. bcr06). You can see the following documentation: https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Pod/

Comment: I recommend to use this method to retrieve information about PODs in SoftLayer https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Pod/getAllObjects/ it will returns an array of Softlayer_Network_Pod which are the datatype than @F.Ojeda commented before